# How can I change the label of the button using ICommand in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, icommand

I have the following button in my view Home.xaml.  I have it binding to a property called StartStopLabel.  I have implemented the interface `ICommand` in the same view and I could able to change the label to text "Stop" after clicking on Start(which is the initial status which I am setting in the constructor of the view as `this.StartStopLabel="Start",this.ButtonStatus="click on start button")`, but I am not able to do the reverse that is changing the label of button from "Stop" to "Start" .What I mean to say is `ICommand` is not notified of the click event when the button label shows "Stop".

Once user clicks on the "stop" button(i.e. when the button label shows the text "stop" ) I want to change the text of the textblock "BtnSTatus" to "You have clicked on start button" and back to "Click on Start button" when the button label again shows text "Start".

Any suggestions how to fix these two issues?

My View:

```
<Button  Name="btnStartStop" Content="{Binding StartStopLabel}"  Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"  />
 <TextBlock Name="BtnStatus" Content="{Binding ButtonStatus}">
```

View.Cs code:

```
    private string _startStopLabel;
    public string StartStopLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return _startStopLabel;
        }
        set
        {                
            _startStopLabel =  value;                
            RaisePropertyChanged("StartStopLabel");
        }
    } 

    private string _ButtonStatus;
    public string ButtonStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _ButtonStatus;
        }
        set
        {                
            _ButtonStatus =  value;                
            RaisePropertyChanged("ButtonStatus");
        }
    }
```

ClickCommand event which is part of ICommand implementation in View.cs:

```
  public System.Windows.Input.ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand((o) =>
            {
                this.StartStopLabel = "Stop";
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    //call service on a background thread here...

                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you set DataContext = this? And bindings are case sensitive. ButtonStatus (in your RaisePropertyChanged), is not the same thing as ButtonSTatus (in your XAML). It also looks like you're only setting the StartStopLabel text to Stop when it's clicked. You're never resetting it to Start.

Comment: Yes, the datacontext is set properly and updated the typo with ButtonStatus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in the

```
public System.Windows.Input.ICommand ClickCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new DelegateCommand(....
```

basically every time that property gets evaluated you will have a new command being generated. So your command that you are bound to won't be the same one that you are changing the state of.

Change your implementation to create the command in advance and return the same one.

```
private System.Windows.Input.ICommand _clickCommand = new DelegateCommand((o) =>
        {
            this.StartStopLabel = "Stop";
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //call service on a background thread here...

            });
        });
public System.Windows.Input.ICommand ClickCommand { get { return _clickCommand; }}
```

In addition you will commonly see the pattern of creating the _clickCommand as a `Lazy<ICommand>` so that it only gets created on first usage.

Comment: In your code above you have hardcoded value "Stop". How do you know on which button(Start or Stop) user has clicked so that you can change it to Start from Stop or to Stop from Start ?

Comment: @krrishna You either check the text of the button or keep an internal state.

Comment: @MillieSmith I would go for checking the text of the button at that moment using property StartStopLabel to change it to Start from Stop or to Stop from Start .

Comment: @AlSki I get a syntax error saying , "keyword "this" is not available  in the current context "

Comment: @krrishna Not right now it's not. You **can** pass it via the CommandParameter in XAML, but I'd recommend against it. If I were you I'd keep an internal boolean that knows whether your background thread is running or not. Much cleaner down the line.

Comment: @MillieSmith Smith, where do I change the text of the textblock ButtonStatus ? Same place where I will update the button label from start to stop or stop to start ?

Comment: Yes. Wherever you toggle the boolean.

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose to change the ClickCommand property so that it returns different commands for start and stop with different texts:

1. ClickCommand is initialized with Start command.
2. User executes command.
3. Actions for start are executed through ICommand.Execute.
4. ClickCommand is changed to return Stop command. OnPropertyChanged is raised for ClickCommand so that the UI binds to the new command.
5. User executes command.
6. Actions for stop are executed through ICommand.Execute.
7. ClickCommand is changed to return Start command. OnPropertyChanged is raised for ClickCommand so that the UI binds to the new command.
   ...

Comment: I like this (I upvoted it), but it still doesn't answer his question as to why it's not updating.

Comment: It would be great if you can tell me how do you change this code to do the same ..

Comment: You're right. Somehow I remembered that the ICommand Interface also has a text property which is not the case. So the answer does not solve the Problem.